# Error while downloading file from web server UrlConnection

Tags: android, urlconnection, okhttp

I'm having problem with UrlConnection class on LGE G2 device. Somehow same code is working on other devices. Also, when I change URL to another one, it seems that DL is working. So there is possibility that problem is on server part.

I also tested code towards same URL on Galaxy SIV with 4.4.2 android, and it seems that everything works normally.

Also, I can dl file from same URL using any web browser...

This is stack trace:

```
04-17 12:17:35.681: W/System.err(10695): java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: HTTP/1.1 
04-17 12:17:35.681: W/System.err(10695):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.setStatusLine(RawHeaders.java:108)
04-17 12:17:35.681: W/System.err(10695):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
04-17 12:17:35.681: W/System.err(10695):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
04-17 12:17:35.681: W/System.err(10695):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
04-17 12:17:35.681: W/System.err(10695):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
04-17 12:17:35.681: W/System.err(10695):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
04-17 12:17:35.681: W/System.err(10695):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:143)
04-17 12:17:35.681: W/System.err(10695):    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldInt(URLConnection.java:544)
04-17 12:17:35.681: W/System.err(10695):    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:316)
```

Code:

```
URL url = new URL(resource);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(TEST_TIMEOUT);
connection.setReadTimeout(TEST_TIMEOUT);

int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();

InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                inputStream);
```

It's standard usage of UrlConnection. Same happens when using HttpUrlConnection or HttpsUrlConnection. And as I said this error occurs only on LGE G2. I tested it on Nexus 4, Xperia Z1 and Galaxy SIV where everything works as it should!
BR,
JDK

Comment: Hi, I edited question with code.